# Display media in tweet via API?

Tags: php, twitter

I have a picture sharing website that when people post a picture, it updates their twitter status with a link to it.

With the new Twitter layout, the allow something called "Tweet Media" where they will show media from the link you posted in your tweet.

My question is - how do I do that? Do I have to modify my PHP script that updates my tweet? The page that contains the image to tell Twitter what image to show?

Thanks!
Coulton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying embedded media links in the right pane of the new Twitter UI is something that is done by Twitter. You can't make it happen by yourself. They look for URls with known patterns and then display the media listed in the URL. You should contact Twitter at api@twitter.com, and make them aware of your service. If they see a high enough usage, they will add it to their UI code.

Comment: Thanks! I looked everywhere for it!