# Is there a public API or meta data to integrate with Twitter new media system?

Tags: twitter, meta-tags

Now that twitter is on a media rampage you can see on twitter pictures and youtube videos directly imported from a few sites.
Twitpic also has a full integration with Twitter.

My question is : Are there some metatags that I can add so that Twitter pick up the pictures from my site ? A special declaration to make somewhere ? I wasn't able to find any documentation and I'm afraid this is only a special integration with authorized partners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would normally flag this as a dupe, but since I recently discovered two questions regarding this topic instead of one. I'll add them below . .

[How do I add an image to a tweet or how does twitter decide which image urls to render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931396/how-do-i-add-an-image-to-a-tweet-or-how-does-twitter-decide-which-image-urls-to-r/7072734#7072734)

[Display media in tweet via API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531571/display-media-in-tweet-via-api/5533346#5533346)

. . also Twitter is releasing an API related to the images, however it's not out yet.

https://support.twitter.com/articles/20156423

Comment: Photo upload integration was recently added to the API, https://dev.twitter.com/blog/photo-upload-api